# Open PDF while running Unity application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

Recently I was trying to create an app in Unity where with a button I could open an image or a pdf while the app remains open and running. I thought that maybe if I defined several 2D Empty Objects (as Images, Raw Images...) the app would still run while doing this.

I tried to open a pdf file with the Hololens emulator and, although it opened the pdf with the Microsoft Edge, the app stopped running. To open the pdf file I manage to used the WWW class.

I was wondering if there is a way that I could open the pdf file and it doesn't break the entire process of the app, something like a pop-up link. If there is no way to do this, how did you manage (how do you think is possible) to open a pdf while running an app?

Comment: Can the Hololens even *handle* PDFs?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the,

```
Application.OpenURL(file:///...../myFile.pdf)
```

Else you would have to use one of the embedded browsers available for unity inside the Asset store.